# When should I submit my firebase push notification token to server?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I use this vuex action for registering my push notification token with my server:

```
  async submitPushToken({commit, getters}) {
    commit('SET_PUSH_TOKEN', await firebase.getCurrentPushToken());
    return api
      .post('/push/register/', {registration_id: getters.pushToken})
      .catch(e => alert(`You won't receive notifications because ${e}`));
  },
```

When should I register my push token, after user registration, after each login? After every update to application?
When Does the token get updated itself?

Comment: It's really upto you, when you want to do it. In my opinion upon login would be good, unless you want to send notification to a user who hasn't logged in to app yet.

Comment: @Manoj but when does the token change?

Comment: `getCurrentPushToken()` always gives you the current push token. So you could probably update the token when you validate user's stored credentials / auth token.

Comment: @Manoj my point is that I don't want to send the token to server if the server already has it. I want to know when the current push token changes so I only send it to the server then. I know I could just check in my server if the token is the same as before but I would like to send the token only when it needs to be sent.

Comment: Then you will have to create a custom message service and use onNewToken callback which will be called whenever token is updated.

Comment: @Manoj but doesn't it have a rule? don't we know when the token is renewed in firebase? how is the token generated? Why can't I know when firebase changes the token so I can only call getCurrentPushToken then? I don't understand.

Comment: Yes you can know when new token is created by implementing onNewToken - I suggest you to read https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService#onNewToken(java.lang.String) or if you want to keep it simple save old token in app settings, call get current token, compare both if they are different hit the API.